# Complicated where request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables in my rails app: properties and requests. Both tables have field called `address`. But in property address is always single value like Hollywood for example and in request table there could be complicated string like `["Hollywood", "Beverley Hills"]`. My task is to get all properties which match by address. It means that if we have in request `["Hollywood", "Beverley Hills"]` i need all properties that have address as Hollywood and all Beverley Hills. I tried something like this:

```
@properties = Property.where("address = ? ", @request.address)
```

and:

```
@properties = Property.where("address IN (?) ", @request.address)
```

but both variants don't work and i think because @request.address is actually string, not array.
So i would like if somebody would suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first try is wrong, as `address` in `Property` is a single value.

Your second try is correct but not the best.

You can use `Property.where(address: @request.address)`. But you have to be sure that `@request.address` is an Array of String.

You shouldn't save an `Array` as a `String` like that: `"[\"Hollywood\", \"Beverley Hills\"]`. It is too hard to parse in the application. If you want to save this way, you will be better using `serialize :address, Array` in the model, because then it will return an Array when you try to access the attribute.

Anyway, check if `@request.address` in an Array of String, if not, parse it to be an Array of String.

Comment: First variant also works if make @request.address as array

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap it in an array

```
@properties = Property.where(address: [@request.address])
```